# How to convert N local topmost commits to an MQ patch?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I would like to arrange my last commits as an MQ patch. All the commits are local (never pushed to the server), but not all the local commits are to be converted.

Say, I did 10 commits (never pushed) and now I wish to convert the last 5 to a patch.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short version:

```
$ hg qimport -r "-5:"
```

Long version:

```
$ hg qimport -r "last(all(), 5)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import changesets via `hg qimport` if you've already got an MQ repository initialised (via `hg qinit`. The command only accepts one patch at a time, so to import your last five changesets, you'd need to run the command five times and specify the revision to import via the `--rev XXX` parameter.

If your using TortoiseHG, you can import patches from within the TortoiseHG Workbench by right-clicking the changeset to import, then selecting Modify History -> Import to MQ.