# How do I convert a Mercurial queues patch to local changes only?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297889/how-to-convert-n-local-topmost-commits-to-an-mq-patch) shows how you can demote a commit to a patch, but how can I convert an mq patch to local changes only?

Comment: Sorry, but mq-patch **is** already "local changes only", AFAIK. Why do you want something more?

Comment: 'Local changes' is Mercurial terminology for changes that are not in a changeset or tracked by a Mercurial patch. There can be several reasons for wanting to convert a patch back into local changes. Anyway, I've needed to do this several times and didn't find the answer on Stack Overflow nor through googling (I had to RTFM), so I shared the answer when I found it in case others want to do the same.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Short answer**

Make sure the patch is applied, then:

```
hg qrefresh nothing
hg qpop --keep-changes
hg qdelete "Name of patch"
```

**Long answer**

First, you need to make sure no changes are tracked by the patch. To do that, use

```
hg qrefresh nothing
```

`nothing` is just a random file name that is *not* in the repository. I usually use `hg qref 0` for brevity. `hg qrefresh` accepts an optional file pattern. If it is given, the patch will track the changes that match the pattern - and only those. When nothing matches the file pattern, no changes will be tracked by the patch, and thus there will be local changes only.

Now you have a useless patch lying around, and you have some local changes. To clean up, you can do

```
hg qpop --keep-changes
```

to pop the patch even though there are local changes. Finally, to remove the dead, empty and unapplied patch you can use

```
hg qrm "Name of patch"
```

You can't remove an applied patch, which is why you need the `hg qpop --keep-changes` step.

(Note: `hg qrm` and `hg qremove` are aliases of `hg qdelete`.)

**If using TortoiseHg**

With TortoiseHg, exporting the patch to the clipboard (Workbench > right-click the patch > Export > Copy Patch), then unapplying the patch, and finally importing from the clipboard with the destination being "Working Directory" seems to work. Here are some screen captures demonstrating this procedure:
[image]

Comment: `--keep-changes` is no longer a valid option for `hg qpop`. According to `hg help qpop`, it seems `--force` is now the option that acheives what we want here:

"-f --force forget any local changes to patched files"

Comment: `hg qrefresh 0` fails with 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

The alternative I've found (powershell syntax): `hg qrefresh --exclude "$(hg root)"`. This tells MQ to exclude everything in the repository. For whatever reason, just `.` didn't work, and I had to specify the full path (therefore, `hg root`).

Comment: @CraftyThumber I still see `--keep-changes`, and AFAICT `--force` will lose the changes we're trying to save.

Comment: I'd use @duplode's option since it is easier and does not use `--keep-changes` or `--force`.  That being said, before I saw that I just successfully ran `hg qpop -f` with Mercurial version 2.0.2 and I still have my local changes, but I first confirmed none of the files were exactly identical names and ran `rsync -av $(hg st -qn) /tmp/` so I have a backup.  Definitely back up your files if you are unsure!

Answer (score 7):

An arguably simpler alternative:

```
hg qfinish qtip
hg strip -k tip
```

That is, finish the patch and then remove the resulting commit while retaining its changes (the `-k` option to `strip`).